# Cumulative Distribution Function from arbitrary Probability Distribution Function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a Probability Distribution Function for a given set of data from a csv file

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=np.loadtxt('data.csv',delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
x_value1= data[:,1]
x_value2= data[:,2]
weight1= data[:,3]
weight2= data[:,4]
```

where weight1 is an array of data that represents the weight for data in x_value1 and weight2 represents the same for x_value2. I produce a histogram where I put the weights in the parameter

```
plt.hist(x_value1,bins=40,color='r', normed=True, weights=weight1, alpha=0.8,    label='x_value1')
plt.hist(x_value2, bins=40,color='b', normed=True, weights=weight2,  alpha=0.6,  label='x_value2')
```

[image]

My problem now is converting this PDF to CDF. I read from one of the posts here that you can use numpy.cumsum() to convert a set of data to CDF, so I tried it together with np.histogram()

```
values1,base1= np.histogram(x_value1, bins=40)
values2,base2= np.histogram(x_value2, bins=40)

cumulative1=np.cumsum(values1)
cumulative2=np.cumsum(values2)

plt.plot(base1[:-1],cumulative1,c='red',label='x_value1')
plt.plot(base2[:-1],cumulative2,c='blue',label='x_value2')

plt.title("CDF for x_value1 and x_value2")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

[image]

I don't know if this plot is right because I didn't include the weights (weight1 and weight2) while doing the CDF. How can I include the weights while plotting the CDF?

Comment: How is `background` and `signal` related to `x_value1` and `x_value2`?  Also, are all your weights integer values?

Comment: It looks like you have a spike in your data for the pdf. For the very highest value I would expect it to be more like zero. You might have a problem loading your data file, or some other error. This is also affecting the cdf.

Comment: @Brionius: sorry about that. It's just typo. I edited the question.

Comment: @Salixalba: I'm sure there's nothing wrong with how I load the data. I just want to include weight1 and weight2 on constructing CDF

Comment: But you do need to beware the outlier in the data. Such outliers will affect things like calculating means and sd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your data correctly, you have a number of samples which have some weight associated with them. Maybe what you want is the experimental CDF of the sample.

The samples are in vector `x` and weights in vector `w`. Let us first construct a Nx2 array of them:

```
arr = np.column_stack((x,w))
```

Then we will sort this array by the samples:

```
arr = arr[arr[:,0].argsort()]
```

This sorting may look a bit odd, but `argsort` gives the sorted order (0 for the smallest, 1 for the second smallest, etc.). When the two-column array is indexed by this result, the rows are arranged so that the first column is ascending. (Using only `sort` with `axis=0` does not work, as it sorts both columns independently.)

Now we can create the cumulative fraction by taking the cumulative sum of weights:

```
cum = np.cumsum(arr[:,1])
```

This must be normalized so that the full scale is 1.

```
cum /= cum[-1]
```

Now we can plot the cumulative distribution:

```
plt.plot(arr[:,0], cum)
```

Now X axis is the input value and Y axis corresponds to the fraction of samples below each level.

Comment: I think this is correct. It works out fine and I got to use the weights. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you explain (in a more simpler way) how does .argsort() works?

Comment: I added some comments on that into my answer. It looks odd, but once you understand how it works, it is very handy. It may help to have a look at `numpy.argsort`'s documentation and try some simple examples yourself.